# Assign a geographic point to a group defined by a polygon in R tidyverse-method

Tags: r, dplyr, raster, r-sp, r-sf

I have yield data with an x and y coordinate. I want to assign each yield point to a county. I have polygons describing counties. Is there a way to do this in the R tidyverse framework?

Load the ggplot2 (just for help visualizing) and dplyr packages

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

Here is a simple example dataset, with two 'counties' I'll call story and love.

```
excnty <- tibble(
  group = c(rep(1, 8), rep(2, 5)),
  cnty = c(rep("story",8), rep("love", 5)),
  order = c(seq(1:8), seq (1:5)),
  Lat = c(3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3,  
          2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
  Lon = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1,
          1, 2, 2, 1, 1))
```

Here is an example of yield data, with x and y coordinates assigned

```
expoints <- tibble(
  yield = c(5, 10),
  Lat = c(1.5, 2.5),
  Lon = c(1.5, 2.5))
```

A visual of the 'counties' and the points

```
excnty %>%
  ggplot(aes(Lat, Lon)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = group, group = group)) + 
  geom_point(data = expoints, aes(Lat, Lon), color = "red", size = 5)
```

The desired dataframe is below

```
desired <- 
  expoints %>%
  mutate(cnty = c("love", "story"))

desired
```

Obviously the county shapes can become much more complex, and I'm unsure how to automate this process. Any help is appreciated, I haven't worked with raster or sp or sf packages, but think they may be of use?

Comment: Is the task to assign a yield to a county based on the coordinates for the given yield? This can be achieved using the `over` function of the `sp` package. Take a look at the following [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137621/join-spatial-point-data-to-polygons-in-r)

Comment: raster will be of little use with vector data, but sf can help :)

Answer (score 3):

I propose a workflow based on the newer {sf} package, specifically function `st_intersection` that spatially combines two objects (i.e. giving county attributes to points lying in that county).

I am using three semi-random cities in NC; for no other reason that a shapefile of North Carolina is included in the {sf} package and is therefore easily available.

Also note that I am using `st_transform` to align the coordinate reference systems of the two spatial objects to a common one [EPSG4326 = WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System), otherwise an error would occur.

The sf package is pipe friendly, but formally outside of the tidyverse ecosystem.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# NC counties - a shapefile shipped with the sf package
shape <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", 
                                 package ="sf")) %>% 
  sf::st_transform(4326) # because WGS84 is a good default

# three cities - note the x and y coordinates
points <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"), crs=4326) # transform to sf object & WGS84 CRS

# a quick overview
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shape) +
  geom_sf(data = points, aes(color = name), show.legend = "point")
```

[image: go tar heels!]

```
#actual calculation
res <- points %>% 
  sf::st_intersection(shape) %>% # perform the intersection
  dplyr::select(city = name, county = NAME) %>% # select relevant columns
  sf::st_set_geometry(NULL) # geometry is no longer required

res
        city      county
2 Greensboro    Guilford
1    Raleigh        Wake
3 Wilmington New Hanover
```